# Where can I find records about German military records from World War II?

Tags: germany, military-records, world-war-2

I am looking for information pertaining to German soldiers during World War II. My significant other's great grandparents were from Germany during the second world war. His great-grandfather was in the Nazi youth program, and fought as a soldier in Italy. He was captured by the Americans in 1941 or 1942 in Italy. I was wondering what kind of records can I find surrounding german POW's or german records.

Comment: @CRSouser - I'm not sure that this is a duplicate question. The soldier in the question did not die in service and was captured by Americans in Italy. There probably is a whole set of U.S. military records that are not included in the linked question, especially if this man was in a POW camp in the USA. Another question, http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9758/how-to-research-german-wwii-prisoners-of-war-in-british-captivity , also deals with German POWs.

Comment: @bgwiehle Valid point, but the protected question is ALSO very broad though to basically cover any German WWII soldiers. Like many other questions that were not marked as dups, if the question though was refined to be very specific or broken out to separate American POW vs. Nazi Youth I would have no problem de-duplicating it.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  The duplicate may cover off on much of your question, so once you have reviewed that, I recommend using the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it to focus it on an aspect that remains unanswered.

Comment: Perhaps ask "How to research German WWII prisoners of war in American captivity?"