# Seeking WW2 service record of Helmut Pelz?

Tags: germany, military-records, world-war-2, navy

I am looking to find my grandfather's service record in the German navy during the Second World War.

He was also a prisoner of war and I have the paper work for this.

Comment: http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/how-to-find-information-on-german-soldiers-from-world-war-i-and-world-war-ii and http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9758/how-to-research-german-wwii-prisoners-of-war-in-british-captivity may be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  If you need more help after reviewing the duplicate then just write down in much more detail what you have tried from the advice listed there.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to revise it.

Comment: @PolyGeo My only question on whether this is a duplicate or not is whether lejonet's answer sufficiently covers naval records? I don't know whether there are any significant differences from other German military records. If so, it might be possible to reword this question to focus on navy records.

Comment: That's a good point @HarryVervet and one that can probably be clarified with input from lejonet and/or more detail from Mark.