# Allied POW camps WWII

Tags: germany, world-war-2, france

My aunt who was born in 1925 said she was a POW towards the end of WWII. She said she was a German Army member, not a Nazi. She said the allieds were French.

How do I find out about these camps?

Comment: Ann, when was your Aunt born -- it it was after 1917, her name must be removed because of this site's privacy policy: https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Rats! She was born in 1925. Do you know if there are any sites that might have POW listings or even German military listings? Thank you

Comment: Ann, you can still ask the question, just without her name.  Not specific to France but you might find https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9758/how-to-research-german-wwii-prisoners-of-war-in-british-captivity?rq=1 useful.

Answer (score 3):

A good starting point would be the [International Committee of the Red Cross](https://www.icrc.org/en/document/request-information-about-individuals-detained-during-second-world-war-or-spanish-civil-war-quota) who have archives about PoWs; however, they operate limits on how many questions they will handle in a quarter and the gates are now closed until October 2017.

They do suggest the following website as a way to pursue your research:

> German military personnel
>
> Deutsche Dienststelle (WASt)
>
> Eichborndamm 179, 13403 Berlin, Germany

Their website is [here](http://www.dd-wast.de)